# What is the correct way to call ASP.NET web APIs from Xamarin mobile app using C# especially for post method

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I've created an ASP.NET Web API project in which I created two api controllers, one is to get all registered users and the second one is to log in to the application through username and password. Whereas I test both methods with the postman, work fine. I'm using BaseAddress property to put URI and I'm putting the "api/controllername/action" in PostAsJsonAsync() method. When I'm debugging my xamarin app code, at `PostAsJasonAsync()` method it's showing-

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 11:13:44 GMT
  Forwarded: host=192.168.20.176:45459; proto=http
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  X-Android-Received-Millis: 1598181223781
  X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 400
  X-Android-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
  X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1598181223764
  Content-Length: 374
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii}.
```

web API controller code is:

```
    public class LoginController : ApiController
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPCon"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        [HttpPost]
        public int Login([FromBody] Login user)
        {
            int ret = 0;
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM Login WHERE UserNames = '" + user.UserName.Trim() + "' and PassWord=" + user.PassWord.Trim();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.Open();
                ret = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

Mobile app code is as below:

```
public void LoginBtnClicked()
        {
            if (Username.Trim() != "" && Password.Trim() != "")
            {
                using(var client=new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ipaddress:45459/"); //I'm using conveyor to get this address and I'm running mobile app in android emulator
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    UserLogin user = new UserLogin
                    {
                        UserName = Username,
                        PassWord = Password
                    };
                    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Login/Login", user).Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var a = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        if (a.Result.ToString().Trim() == "0")
                        {
                            Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Invalid Login Credentials", "Cancel");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Home());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "Internal Server Error", "Ok");
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: do the Login class on the server and the UserLogin class on the client have the same definition?

Comment: yes both have same definition

Comment: Best way of solving issue is with a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare headers in the first request using Postman with c# headers.  Make the c# code look exactly like Postman.  The default headers in c# are not the same as Postman and you either have a wrong header or a missing header.

Comment: Just like @jdweng said, you should check what headers you are adding. Postman generally adds some generic headers, especially not included `language` has caused issues for me in the past. But as it stands, there's no way of knowing exactly what the issue is

Comment: You may need to specify TLS version 1.2 : HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();   

//specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @jdweng I tried every possible way but still, it's not working can anyone suggest me any other way to call APIs in my client-side project.

Comment: Use sniffer.  Fiddler will show with working Postman the version of encryption modes that worked.  You should see with Postman TLS messages (TCP) doing authentication before the htttp request.  See if c# code is doing the same.  Look for any differences  between the Postman and c#.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for putting your efforts into my question. I found a solution by changing the procedure of calling web API on the client-side. I used HttpContent and PostAsync() method instead of BaseAddress and PostAsJsonAsync() methods. code as below:

```
using(HttpClient client=new HttpClient())
                {
                    UserLogin user = new UserLogin
                    {
                        UserName = Username,
                        PassWord = Password
                    };
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
                    HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
                    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                    var uri = new Uri("http://ipaddress/api/UserLogin");
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                    //more conditions and code....
                }
```